# Is there any way to get informative errors from python scripts in hadoop streaming?

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm using python with hadoop streaming.  Despite careful unit testing, errors inevitably creep in.  When they do, this error message is all that hadoop gives:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
...
```

The message is very unhelpful for debugging.

Is there any way to get *informative* errors from python scripts in hadoop streaming?

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

if you have access to the jobtracker for the cluster where you are running you can get to the stderr/stdout of the script by finding the job and looking for the tasks that failed.

Comment: Where exactly should I look?  I'm running my own cluster on EC2, but either it's not reporting stderr/stdout, or I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you know the IP and/or hostname of the node where you are running the jobtracker for your cluter? Usually, you can just get to it through a browser at port 50030 though firewalls sometimes block that port. Another option is if you know the node where a given task faield you can sssh to that node and look for your jobs logs. The exact directory will depend on which hadoop package you are using.

Comment: I can get into the jobtracker at port :50030.  I can see the administration page, job pages, and even task pages, but it won't load  logs.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. You might be able to access the logs via ssh by logging into the node where the failed tasks ran. The location is dependent on your OS and the distribution you are using but you can check /var/logs/hadoop or something. Otherwis,e if you have an admin you can talk to him. The other thing you can do if you are able to recreate is just run the python scripts like a unix pipe over sample input. It usuall goes something like 'cat input | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py'. This will help you catch app-level errors but not issues with your cluster.